# Is FTP (Foil Shielded Twisted Pairs) Cat 6 cable suitable for outdoor use?

Tags: cable

Is FTP (Foil Shielded Twisted Pairs) Cat 6 cable suitable for outdoor use?

I am going to pass the cable from a window via the roof back inside via another window.

Do I need to take special care for thunder/lightning protection?

Comment: How long a distance is this travelling?

Comment: Also, you might find this Q&A helpful http://superuser.com/questions/32903/running-cat5-cable-outdoors?rq=1

Comment: The shop selling the cable told me it os FTP Oiled cat6 outdoor cable. Estimated travel distance is 30 to 40m via the roof of outdoor wall of the house